# Key error when using regex quantifier python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am trying to capture words following specified stocks in a pandas df. I have several stocks in the format `$IBM` and am setting a python regex pattern to search each tweet for 3-5 words following the stock if found.

My df called `stock_news` looks as such:

```
   Word       Count

0  $IBM     10
1  $GOOGL   8  
etc

pattern = ''
for word in stock_news.Word:
    pattern += '{} (\w+\s*\S*){3,5}|'.format(re.escape(word))
```

However my understanding is that `{}` should be a quantifier, in my case matching between 3 to 5 times however I receive the following `KeyError`:

```
KeyError: '3,5'
```

I have also tried using rawstrings with `r'{} (\w+\s*\S*){3,5}|'` but to no avail. I also tried using this pattern on regex101 and it seems to work there but not in my Pycharm IDE. Any help would be appreciated.

Code for finding:

```
pat = re.compile(pattern, re.I)

for i in tweet_df.Tweets:
    for x in pat.findall(i):
        print(x)
```

Comment: To use  a literal brace in f-string or format string, double it

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for the help. This is now just matching whitespace e.g.

Comment: ('', '', '', '', '', '', '')
('', '', '', '', '', '', '')

Comment: Do you know why this would be? I thought it had to match word characters

Comment: Probably I do, but what is your code?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I added my code to the question

Comment: Ok, so you extract multiple occurrences of `\$IBM (\w+\s*\S*){3,5}|\$GOOGLE (\w+\s*\S*){3,5}|`, see the last empty `|`? You are not building the pattern right.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ah I see the problem. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: I believe you need `(?:\$IBM|\$GOOGLE)\s+(\w+(?:\s+\S+){3,5})` regex. Try `pattern = r'(?:{})\s+(\w+(?:\s+\S+){{3,5}})'.format("|".join(map(re.escape, stock_news['Word'])))`. Please check and let know if it works or not.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This is exactly what I need. many thanks. Would you mind explaining the `?:` so I can understand the theory behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you build your pattern, there is an empty alternative left at the end, so your pattern effectively matches any string, every empty space before non-matching texts.

You need to build the pattern like

```
(?:\$IBM|\$GOOGLE)\s+(\w+(?:\s+\S+){3,5})
```

You may use

```
pattern = r'(?:{})\s+(\w+(?:\s+\S+){{3,5}})'.format(
              "|".join(map(re.escape, stock_news['Word'])))
```

Mind that the **literal curly braces inside an f-string or a format string must be doubled**.

**Regex details**

- `(?:\$IBM|\$GOOGLE)` - a [*non-capturing* group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions) matching either `$IBM` or `$GOOGLE`
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(\w+(?:\s+\S+){3,5})` - Capturing group 1 (when using `str.findall`, only this part will be returned):

  - `\w+` - 1+ word chars
  - `(?:\s+\S+){3,5}` - a non-capturing* group matching three, four or five occurrences of 1+ whitespaces followed with 1+ non-whitespace characters

Note that *non-capturing groups* are meant to *group* some patterns, or quantify them, without actually allocating any memory buffer for the values they match, so that you could *capture* only what you need to return/keep.